# Powershell sorts by MM/DD/YY, HH:MM AM/PM

Tags: powershell, csv, date, sorting, time

Importing a CSV file that has date/time values a column "Expiration" as "MM/DD/YY, HH:MM AM" (or PM). When I parse through the file I store it in an object of type System.Collections.ArrayList (not sure that matters) and I'd like to export the results in descending date/time order. When I use:

```
Sort-Object -Property Expiration -Descending
```

It sorts the results mostly in order but by the 1st integer of the DD portion so it looks like this:

```
2/1/21, 3:54 AM
2/11/21, 7:59 AM
2/2/21, 4:44 AM
2/21/21, 6:24 AM
2/3/21, 3:58 AM
2/4/21, 3:59 AM
```

What can I do to get this sorted properly upon export? I also tried sorting A-Z in Excel upon output but it does the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

That is because these are strings, not real DateTime objects. You need to make them DateTime objects.

By default, this...

```
2/1/21, 3:54 AM
2/11/21, 7:59 AM
2/2/21, 4:44 AM
2/21/21, 6:24 AM
2/3/21, 3:58 AM
2/4/21, 3:59 AM
```

... on import will be separate columns if no header is specified, and only the date, not time, if the property used. These strings must be properly quoted to be read as one column.

```
"Expiration"
"2/1/21, 3:54 AM"
"2/11/21, 7:59 AM"
"2/2/21, 4:44 AM"
"2/21/21, 6:24 AM"
"2/3/21, 3:58 AM"
"2/4/21, 3:59 AM"
```

Example - Date actions

```
Sort-Object { $PSitem.Expiration -as [datetime] }

# Or these
$sortedDates = $dates | 
Sort-Object {[System.DateTime]::ParseExact($PSItem, "MM/dd/yyyy", $null)}

# Or DateTIme parsing/formatting like these
[DateTime]"2020-7-16"

[DateTime]"Jul-16"

'{0:yyyy-MM-dd}' -f [DateTime]'Jul-16'

# Or 
[datetime]::parseexact($PSitem.Expiration, 'dd-MMM-yy', $null)

# Output DateTime
[datetime]::parseexact($PSitem.Expiration, 'dd-MMM-yy', $null).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')

# Or accept the default of ParseExect.
Import-CSV -Path 'C:\Scripts\Dates.csv' | 
ForEach {[DateTime]::Parse($PSitem.Expiration)} | 
Sort-Object

# Results
<#
Monday, February 1, 2021 3:54:00 AM
Tuesday, February 2, 2021 4:44:00 AM
Wednesday, February 3, 2021 3:58:00 AM
Thursday, February 4, 2021 3:59:00 AM
Thursday, February 11, 2021 7:59:00 AM
Sunday, February 21, 2021 6:24:00 AM
#>

Import-CSV -Path 'C:\Scripts\Dates.csv' | 
ForEach {[DateTime]::Parse($PSitem.Expiration)} | 
Sort-Object -Descending
# Results
<#
Sunday, February 21, 2021 6:24:00 AM
Thursday, February 11, 2021 7:59:00 AM
Thursday, February 4, 2021 3:59:00 AM
Wednesday, February 3, 2021 3:58:00 AM
Tuesday, February 2, 2021 4:44:00 AM
Monday, February 1, 2021 3:54:00 AM
#>
```

See also: [PowerTip: Use PowerShell to Format Dates](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powertip-use-powershell-to-format-dates)